# Using the jQuery input mask plugin with a Dart Web UI component

Tags: javascript, jquery, dart, dart-js-interop

I'm trying to use an [input mask](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) jQuery plugin in Dart. The plugin works fine when the element I'm trying to add the mask to isn't in a web component, but when I add it to a web component it no longer works. And for the code that doesn't work I'm able to run `$("#phone-number").mask("(999) 999-9999");` through the chrome console and it works fine.

This code works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body>
    <input id="phone-number" type="text">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/dart">
      import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

      void main() {
        js.scoped(() {
          var a = js.context.jQuery("#phone-number");
          a.mask("(999) 999-9999");
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body>    
    <element name="x-phone-number">
      <template>
        <input id="phone-number">
      </template>
    </element>
    <x-phone-number></x-phone-number>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/dart">
      import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

      void main() {
        js.scoped(() {
          var a = js.context.jQuery("#phone-number");
          a.mask("(999) 999-9999");
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely down to components not being fully ready until after the main loop has run once, try adding a Timer to kick off the query like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body>    
    <element name="x-phone-number">
      <template>
        <input id="phone-number">
      </template>
    </element>
    <x-phone-number></x-phone-number>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/dart">
      import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;
      import 'dart:async';

      void _postMainSetup() {
        js.scoped(() {
          var a = js.context.jQuery("#phone-number");
          a.mask("(999) 999-9999");
        });
      }

      void main() {
        Timer.run(_postMainSetup);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also added the interop.js script which is required in latest SDK as jsinterop functionality has been split out from dart.js.